# Google Analytics Management API upload limits not clear

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics Management [Upload API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData), I would like to upload small amount of data but unfortunately API only supports 50 upload requests per day. I cannot see this quota limits on management console, and when I trace the logs I can see "Quota limit exceeded." error. This error does not indicate the root cause, and I do not know how to determine error by exploring quotas.

Current dashboard: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/quotas

[image]

Comment: Why are you uploading data to Universal analytics accounts?

Comment: I’m using user related data for marketing purposes. Should I use another API instead?